# If conditions false then prevent default

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements, preventdefault

I have a link. When some one clicks on that I want to check some conditions before letting it work. If it's `false` the default action should be prevented.

```
$(".pager-next a.active").click(function(event) {
    if (!a == 1) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }           
});
```

The link should only work if `a` is equal to `1`. Is the above code correct. `a` is set to `1` if a particular condition is met. The link should only work if the condition is met.

Comment: *Is the above code correct* Why do you ask? Do you have problems? If yes, which ones?

Comment: What's `a`? Can you post it in your code?

Comment: Be careful, there's a difference between `==` and `===`. If you want to check whether `a` is equal to the integer `1` then you should use `a===1`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use for the difference.

Comment: Based on your explanation, I think you mean `a != 1` instead of `!a == 1`.

Comment: lol caught it. **Mathias Bynens** is right, I'm pretty sure that's your problem but could also be wrong type comparison.

Comment: I have updated the question. @Thomas i wanted to actually compare it.

Comment: This might be helpful as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: @Mathias I think I mean it like that. Let me try.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming by '*should only work if a is equal to 1*' you mean the text of the `a` element is equal to 1, try this:

```
$(".pager-next a.active").click(function(event) {
    if ($(this).text() != "1") {
        event.preventDefault();
    }           
});
```

You can amend `text()` to use whichever attribute of the element is available to you in jQuery.

**UPDATE**

> my a is a var which hold the value 0 until a condition is met.

In which case, the problem was simply that your equality operator was incorrect:

```
$(".pager-next a.active").click(function(event) {
    if (a != 1) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }            
});
```

Comment: my a is a var which hold the value 0 until a condition is met.

Comment: In order to not confuse yourself it might be worth you using `true` and `false` instead of `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 4):

Be careful:

`!a` evaluates to true or false. If a conversion of `a` to a bool is `true` then `!a` evaluates to false.

All positive integers evaluate to `true`. So `!a` will evaluate to false. A comparison using double equals `==` to 1 will test that boolean `!a` with the boolean `1` or `true`. So if `a` is a positive integer as I suspect it is then your `if` statement will ALWAYS evaluate to false.

If you want to test is something is NOT something else you need to change the first equals in your comparison operator (`===`) to be a `!`.

E.g. `var a = 2; if(a!==1) { // do something }` <-- A is 2 and therefore the if comparison wille evaluate to true as `a` *does not* equal `1`.

In your code we have:

```
var a = 2;
if(!a==1){
  // a was 2 (or boolean true by default)
  // but using ! has negated its boolean value
  // so !a evaluates to boolean false
  // which is being compared to 1 (evaluating to boolean true)
  // so this if statement will never get here
}
```

Hope that helps

P.S. Remember your comparison operators:

```
!"hello world" == 0 // true
!"hello world" === 0 // false
```

## Update

I saw your comment on another post which said that `a` is `0` until something happens then it is `1`.

In this case:

```
var a = 0; // integer 0 or bool false
if(!a==1){ // if the bool opposite of 0 (false) is equal to 1 (true)
  // well, opposite of false is true, so you're checking if true is equal to true
  // so this will get called
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot that was very comprehensive explanation. Learned a lot more than I asked.