# Don't execute href jquery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery if conditions false then prevent default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376089/jquery-if-conditions-false-then-prevent-default)

I have this code, it's running fine but I want it to be dynamic.

```
$(".nav a").click(function () {     
    var getid = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#background-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#page_box").fadeOut("slow");         
    $("header").fadeOut("slow");
    $("footer").fadeOut("slow", function () {
        window.location = getid+".php";
    });
});
```

I want to execute the fade out first before directing it using the href.

What I want is this first

```
$(".nav a").click(function () {     
    var getid = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#background-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#page_box").fadeOut("slow"); 
    $("header").fadeOut("slow");
    $("footer").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

then trigger this after

```
.nav a = href = "link"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `event.preventDefault()` first to stop the link behaviour, then manually redirect the user. Try this:

```
$(".nav a").click(function (e) {     
    e.preventDefault();

    var getid = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#background-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#page_box").fadeOut("slow");         
    $("header").fadeOut("slow");
    $("footer").fadeOut("slow", function () {
        location.assign = getid + ".php";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$(".nav a").click(function (e) {     

    e.preventDefault(); /*  If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered. e.g clicked anchors will not take the browser to a new URL */

    var pageUrl = this.id + ".php";

    $("#background-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#page_box").fadeOut("slow"); 
    $("header").fadeOut("slow");
    $("footer").fadeOut("slow", function () {
        window.location.replace(pageUrl);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$(".nav a").click(function (e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
    var $ele = $(this);
    $("#background-wrapper, #page_box, header, footer").fadeOut("slow", function () {
        window.location = $ele.attr('id')+".php";
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This one is working with me. I just removed the .php at the end since I want it to have a external url also. Thanks again :)

Comment: great stuff! don't forget to accept your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will work for you?

```
$(".nav a").click(function (e) {     
    e.preventDefault();
    var pageUri = $(this).attr('id') + '.php';
    $("#background-wrapper, #page_box, header, footer").fadeOut('slow', function () {
        window.replace(pageUri)
    });
}
```